# What are the available options to identify and remove the invalid objects in Postgres (ex: corrupted indexes)

Tags: postgresql

What are the available options to identify and remove the invalid objects in Postgres

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid object?"

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm not sure what you mean by 'invalid objects'. Are you refering to fixing broken sequences, removing broken indexes, purging data that doesn't match a string format?

Comment: I have identified several indexes (pg_class entries with corresponding files on disk) that seem to be "orphaned". For example, pg_class has the following row for an index named " history_setID_temp_index": 

"history_setID_temp_index";16598;0;10;403;345289902;0;0;0;0;0;f;f;"i";1;0;0;0;0;0;f;f;f;f;0;"";"" 

We have files 345289902, 345289902.1, 345289902.2....., up to 345289902.15 on disk (close to 16GB total), but 

drop index mci."history_setID_temp_index" 
returns 
ERROR: cache lookup failed for index 345289902 

How can I get rid of this index and the corresponding disk files, and identify

Answer (score 8):

If you're referring to detecting "invalid" (poorly created) indexes, apparently Postgres can "fail" in an attempt to create an index, and then the query planner won't use them, though they exist in your system.  This query will detect "failed" indexes:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/pgupgrade-bug-invalid-concurrently-created-indexes

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n,
       pg_catalog.pg_index i
WHERE  (i.indisvalid = false OR i.indisready = false) AND
       i.indexrelid = c.oid AND c.relnamespace = n.oid AND
       n.nspname != 'pg_catalog' AND
       n.nspname != 'information_schema' AND
       n.nspname != 'pg_toast'
```

though I suppose detecting TOAST table indexes wouldn't hurt, so you can remove that portion of the query :)

Related, for me sometimes just running a fresh ANALYZE on a table also makes indexes suddenly start being used in production (i.e. even if indexes aren't "invalid" they may be unused until an ANALYZE run).  Weird.

Comment: If you want a simple query that will give just a list of invalid indexes: `SELECT pg_class.relname FROM pg_class, pg_index WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;`.

Comment: And how would you then drop those invalid indexes?

Comment: @thouliha Looks like drop and recreate the normal way: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158404/how-can-i-determine-why-a-concurrent-postgres-index-was-marked-as-invalid

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `vacuum full pg_class` as superuser?

Also, auto-vacuum should take care of it eventually. Your objects seem to be temporary tables/indexes, and the catalog is (usually) not being updated as frequently as your data.