# Postgresql planner uses wrong index

Tags: sql, postgresql

Recently i upgraded Postgresql from 9.1 to 9.2 version. New planner uses wrong index and query executes too long.

Query:

```
explain SELECT mentions.* FROM mentions WHERE (searches_id = 7646553) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1000
```

Explain in 9.1 version:

```
Limit  (cost=5762.99..5765.49 rows=1000 width=184)
->  Sort  (cost=5762.99..5842.38 rows=31755 width=184)
    Sort Key: id
    ->  Index Scan using mentions_searches_id_idx on mentions  (cost=0.00..4021.90 rows=31755 width=184)
          Index Cond: (searches_id = 7646553)
```

Expain in 9.2 version:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..450245.54 rows=1000 width=244)
->  Index Scan using mentions_pk on mentions  (cost=0.00..110469543.02 rows=245354 width=244
    Index Cond: (id > 0)"
    Filter: (searches_id = 7646553)
```

The correct approach is in 9.1 version, where planner uses index on searches_id. In 9.2 version planner doesn't not uses that index and filter rows by searches_id.

When i execute on 9.2 version query without ORDER BY id, planner uses index on searches_id, but i need to order by id.

I also tried to select rows in subquery and order it in second query, but explain shows that, the planner do the same like in normal query.

```
select * from (
SELECT mentions.* FROM mentions WHERE (searches_id = 7646553))
AS q1
order by id asc
```

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If searches_id #7646553 rows are more than a few percent of the table then the index on that column will not be used as a table scan would be faster. Do a

```
select count(*) from mentions where searches_id = 7646553
```

and compare to the total rows.

If they are less than a few percent of the table then try

```
with m as (
    SELECT *
    FROM mentions
    WHERE searches_id = 7646553
)
select *
from m
order by id asc
```

(From PostgreSQL v12 on, you have to use `with ... as materialized`.)

Or create a composite index:

```
create index index_name on mentions (searches_id, id)
```

If searches_id has low [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) then create the same index in the opposite order

```
create index index_name on mentions (id, searches_id)
```

Do

```
analyze mentions
```

After creating an index.

Comment: @Pajak Did you try the CTE I suggested? `with...`

Comment: Thx for help. But the problem aren't to many rows with searches_id #7646553. There is only 65 rows and the table mentions has 150mln total rows.

When i explain query select count(*) from mentions where searches_id = 7646553, it uses properly index on searches_id.
I wouldn't like to create new indexes, because i think the searches_id is proper index to be executed.

Comment: Right now the best solution, which i found, is to execute
     set  enable_indexscan = false;
before running the query, and switch to true, after the query. It works,but it isn't elegant solution.

Comment: @Pajak BTW did you `analyze` the db after the load into 9.2?

Comment: you were right with analyze - after doing it, planner choose proper index. I didn't do analyze afeter loading data to 9.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had indexes but they were all based on 3 columns, and I wasn't calling out one of the columns in the indexes, so it was doing seq scan across the entire thing.  Possible fix: more indexes but that use fewer columns (and/or switch column order).

Another problem we saw was that we had the right index, but apparently it was an "invalid" (poorly created CONCURRENT?) index.  So dropping it and creating it (or reindexing it) and it started using it.

[What are the available options to identify and remove the invalid objects in Postgres (ex: corrupted indexes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102136/what-are-the-available-options-to-identify-and-remove-the-invalid-objects-in-pos/29260046#29260046)

See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-multicolumn.html